# Different approach for pagination - LIMIT when using SQLSRV

Tags: pagination, sqlsrv

I'm trying to make an instant pagination using SQLSRV and PHP, I have successfully did this using MySQL but unable to do so when using SQL Server as it does not support LIMIT.

I have the following codes working in MySQL and I wanted to apply the same thing in sqlsrv but since this is not possible, I'm looking forward in creating a different approach(code) to achieve this, can someone give me an idea or a walkthrough to make this happen please, thanks in advanced.

```
if(isset($_POST['page'])):
$paged=$_POST['page'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `member` ORDER BY `member`.`member_id` ASC";


if($paged>0){
       $page_limit=$resultsPerPage*($paged-1);
       $pagination_sql=" LIMIT  $page_limit, $resultsPerPage";
       }
else{
$pagination_sql=" FETCH 0 , $resultsPerPage";
}

$result=sqlsrv_query($sql.$pagination_sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, I hope you find it helpful

```
$paged = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

//Initialize these values
$Table = 'your_tbl_name';          //Table name
$IndexColumn = 'pk_col_name';      //Primary key column
$resultsPerPage = '10';            //Page size
$Where = '';                //Optional WHERE clause, may leave empty
$Order = '';                //Optional ORDER clause, may leave empty

$top = ($paged>0) ? $resultsPerPage * ($paged-1) : 0 ;                        
$limit = 'TOP ' . $resultsPerPage ;

$pagination_sql = "SELECT $limit *
    FROM $Table
    $Where ".(($Where=="")?" WHERE ":" AND ")." $IndexColumn NOT IN
    (
        SELECT $IndexColumn FROM
        (
            SELECT TOP $top *
            FROM $Table
            $Where
            $Order
        )
        as [virtTable]
    )
    $Order"; 

$result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $pagination_sql);
```